Particle independence of time test
I have a series of observations of a particle positions (x_i, y_i) (let it be in 2-d), each made at time t_i using some detector that not precise and makes some noise. We can assume that this noise is normally distributed. I want to check a hypothesis that my particle doesn't move in terms that its position is independent of time, with some confidence. Can you recommend me which methods I can use for this task?

If it did move (rather than just having independent measure errors), you might expect some autocorrelation in the reported positions.

Let me start by quoting this from the NIST excellent Engfineering Statistics Handbook: "It is unhelpful to find, after you have finished all the experimental runs, that the measurement devices you have at your disposal cannot measure the changes you were hoping to see. Plan to check this out before embarking on the experiment itself."
The issue you are dealing here is that of measurement system "capability". Is the variability introduced by your measurement system (instrument+operator+...) s small enough proportion of the total variability that you can consider it "capable" of measuring what you are trying to measure. The general "rule of thumb" is that if the measurement system is responsible of 1% or less of the total variability, it is judged capable (what this means practically is that you can ignore the measuring system noise). If that proportion is less than 10%, then it may be capable, depending on other factors (your specific application, required precision, etc.). Above 10% it is generally regarded is "not capable" (i.e. practically, go get a better measurement system).
So you need to characterize your measurement system (precision, accuracy, resolution, etc.). So can you get a particle you know will not move, and measure it, multiple times? That will tell you how much noise your measurement system introduces, and you can compare this to the range of motions you are trying to detect. Or can you get a particle to go on a known trajectory? Again, if so, you can estimate the noise of your measurement system. And as a previous comment noted, if particles are going on defined trajectories, a simple 3D scatter plot should show a trajectory, in spite of the noise. But if your particle goes on a random walk...
If you can not do either, I am afraid your experiment can not provide a conclusive result. Did the particle move, but that was swamped by the measurement system noise? Or did the particle stay put? Its is impossible to tell the difference. All you can tell is that the motion, if any, was less than the measurement system's noise. But as you do not know that noise... So unless yor motion is on a defined trajectory, the length of which exceeds (by a lot) the noise of your measurement system, you need to measure your measurement system's noise.
